# Ubuntu Server openLDAP + Windows Server AD LDS?

Tags: windows, openldap, ad-lds, ubuntu-18.04

Is possible to have a Ubuntu server with openLDAP + Samba and a Windows Server with AD LDS, taking the DDBB from the Ubuntu?

If it's possible could you point me where to find information about this?

Thank you :)